# PowerShell space not detected as space in string

Tags: powershell

I wanna remove all spaces in a string but one space is not detected as a space.
I use ISO 8859-1

$interface[1] is:
Il existe 1 interface sur le système :

I do:
$interface[1].Replace(' ', '')

I get out:
Ilexiste1interfacesurlesystème :

What can I do?

Comment: Are you saying that it otherwise works, except for what _looks_ like a space before the final colon?

Comment: There's different unicode spaces maybe?  Try `-replace '\s'`  Did you copy and paste the actual text?

Comment: If you want to see what that "space" character really is, you can convert the string to bytes and write their values out - something like ```[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($interface[1])```. If it's really a space the last few bytes will display as ```109 101 32 58```, where ```32``` is the space character. If it's something else - e.g. a Unicode "No-Break Space" it might end with something like ```109 101 194 160 58``` where ```194 160``` is a No-Break Space character. Post your output and someone can probably work out what the character is...